# How to strip some paths but not all for Kubernetes nginx-ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-ingress

I have the following block that I'm putting together for a simple web app. I want all traffic with the `/api` prefix to be routed to the backend with the `/api` part stripped out. Everything else I want to be routed to the front end as is. Based on other answers and the Nginx documentation I know that I need the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2` annotation and I can get the backend routes to work with `path: /api(/|$)(.*)`. My question is what is the best practice to configure the front end to accept anything else? Or am I approaching this wrong?

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: primary
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: ...
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: svc-front
            port:
              number: 80
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /api(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          service:
            name: svc-back
            port:
              number: 3000
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - ...
      secretName: tls-secret
```

*desired results:*

- /api/fetch/stuff > *routed to backend* as > /fetch/stuff
- /api > *routed to backend* as > /
- /> *routed to frontend* as > /
- /page1 > *routed to frontend* as > /page1

Edit:

Resolved the issue, if you have a BASE_PATH defined in express.js (example /api/v1). The error you receive when attempting to strip out `/api` above results in a `Path / not found` error no matter what you put after this. This can be confusing as it seems like the ingress rule is over stripping the URI. So I had to change the rule to the following to respect the BASE_PATH on the backend:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: primary
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true" 
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: ...
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /api/v1
        backend:
          service:
            name: svc-back
            port:
              number: 80
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: svc-front
            port:
              number: 80
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - ...
      secretName: tls-secret
```

Hopefully, this helps someone else making the same mistake.

Comment: You should post your edit as an answer.